# mysterious key come out of no where in Perl 5.14 hash table

Tags: perl, hash, autovivification

I am using a hash table in my code

```
my %stat = ();
# read files and do some initialization 
# like  $stat{$key} = {k1=>v1, k2=>v2, k3=>v3};
#   I have located the buggy code
# I want to do something according to c1 and c2 parsed from each line of the file
if(!exists $stat{c1}) {   # I thought I would have initialized all possible used keys here, but it is not true as seen below
    $stat{c1} = {k1=>0, k2=>0, k3=>0};
} 
if( $c1 == $c2) {
    $stat{c1}{k1}++;
} else {
    $stat{c1}{k2}++;
    $stat{c2}{k3}++;  #Note: I forgot to check whether $stat{c2} has been initialized here!
}



map {
    my $val = $stat{$_}{k1};  
    print "$val\n";     # run time error shows "use of uninitalized $val"
} keys %stat;
```

I wrote some print statement to debug the program. I found out that some key value mysteriously appears in the hash table "%stat", despite that I've never insert it! Say $stat{510} somehow exists despite that I never insert it, but its value (a hash table reference in my case) was not initialized. I have to write a statement:

```
map { delete $stat{$_} if(!defined $stat{$_}{k1}) } keys %stat;
```

to remove the unwanted keys.

Can you tell me why some mysterious key can appear from (keys %stat)?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: it is called "Autovivification".

Comment: `if (c1 == c2)` ? That looks very wrong. Typo and should be `$c1` and `$c2`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can you tell me why some mysterious key can appear from (keys %stat)?

Because the code you did not show somehow created them.

Perhaps you did `$stat{510}{k1}`? Keep in mind that

```
$stat{510}{k1}
```

is short for

```
$stat{510}->{k1}
```

and

```
$x->{...}
```

does

```
( $x //= {} )->{...}
```

so

```
$stat{510}{k1}
```

does

```
( $stat{510} //= {} )->{k1}
```

Notice how this assigns to `$stat{510}`?

---

Using `map` as a `for` loop is frowned upon.

```
map { delete $stat{$_} if(!defined $stat{$_}{k1}) } keys %stat;
```

is better written as

```
delete $stat{$_} for grep !defined($stat{$_}{k1}), keys %stat;
```

or even

```
delete @stat{ grep !defined($stat{$_}{k1}), keys %stat };
```

Comment: @Fashandge, Let me know if you decide to add the offending code to your question. I can suggest a couple of ways to avoiding the hash element creation in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! Indeed I somehow referred to $stat{510}{k2}, without first initialize the $stat{510} = {k1=0, k2=0, k3=0}.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the buggy code. If you are interested, please take a look at it, and give me a suggestion about how to avoid such errors in the first place, though it seems just because of my carelessness.

Comment: @Fashandge, I was going to suggest some use of `no autovivification;`, but that's not possible there. It's not clear what you want to have happen instead, but since you talk of initialisation, you might just need `$stat{c2} //= ...;`.

Comment: Yes. It seems good to use ( $stat{c2} //= {k1=>0, k2=>0, k3=>0} )->{k3}++, rather than use if(!exists $stat{c2}) ....,   if I just refer to $stat{c2} in one line of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the autovivification. It means that when you refer to a hash entry, it is created without complaint. And if you don't assign a value at that time, it is initialized with a value of `undefined`. So in the part of your code where you have

```
##read files and do some initialization
```

make sure that you are not reading or writing an entry with key `510`.